# GROUP_CONCAT not working as expected

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join, having, having-clause

I have a many to many relationship. Projects table, projects_users table, and users table. I am trying to return a listing of projects, with its associated users. Here is the query I'm using, which works, but only shows a single user, when I know there should be more:

```
    SELECT
        projects.id,
        `projects`.`project_name`,
        ( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `users`.`name`  separator ', ' ) ) AS staff,
FROM `projects`
    INNER JOIN `projects_users` ON (`projects_users`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` )
    INNER JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `projects_users`.`user_id` ) 
    GROUP BY projects.id, `projects_users`.`user_id` 
    HAVING (`projects_users`.`user_id` = 8)
```

There are several users associated with each project and I would expect to return something like "User 1, User 2, User 3". Instead, I only get  "User 1."

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to aggregate the users per project, you should group according to the user_id:

```
SELECT
    projects.id,
    `projects`.`project_name`,
    ( GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `users`.`name`  separator ', ' ) ) AS staff
FROM projects -- was missing in the OP
INNER JOIN `projects_users` ON (`projects_users`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` )
INNER JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `projects_users`.`user_id` ) 
GROUP BY projects.id -- Group by fixed here
HAVING (`projects_users`.`user_id` = 8)
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks!

But if I use the `HAVING (projects_users.user_id = 8)`, I don't see all the rows that include User 8. I only see the rows where User 8 happens to be the first user. Any ideas?

Comment: @cvindr using a `where` clause with an `exists` condition should do the trick

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks for the insight! For anyone else wondering how I made this work: `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT projects_users.user_id FROM projects_users WHERE (   projects_users.user_id = 14 OR    projects_users.user_id = 8) AND projects.id = projects_users.project_id)`